# Downloaded file is corrupted in loopback, hyphens are added

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopbackjs, swagger-ui, loopback

I am using loopback which connects with mongodb. When I try to download a file using loopback UI
GET /containers/{container}/download/{file}
its response is success but when i clicked on link it downloads corrupt file. pdf-sample.pdf
Same URL when I hit on browser it works correctly.
Also when I hit same URL in postman it works.